# Is there a non-ambiguous name for the “square of a function”?

Tags: functions, terminology

Given a function $f$, I want to refer to $f \circ f$ other than by a formula. Is there any name for this other than *square of $f$,* which has the problem of being ambiguous?

In analogy to the [functional square root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_square_root), using the *functional square* suggests itself but I fail to find any usage of this term that is related to mathematics but not not related to functional square roots.

Comment: $f \circ f$ reads $f$ composed $f$ or composition of $f$ with itself, I don't know if there is a shorter name for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that $f\circ f\circ\ldots\circ f\ $ ($n$ times) is called the $n$th iterate and the functional square root is often called half iterate, I'd call $f\circ f$ the **second iterate** of $f$.

Answer (score 2):

The closest you come in words is probably to speak about "$f$ iterated twice" or something like that.